# JK flip flop random start outputs

Tags: flipflop, breadboard, output, random

I am working on a project for college and I have to implement a sort of alarm using only MUX's and JK flip flops and a bread board. The problem I encountered is that whenever I power the whole circuit my flip flops have random outputs. I have 2 SN74HC73's meaning I have 4 flip flops. I connected all ports(correctly, checked three times) and have CLR set to HIGH (basically connect it to the power source) for all 4.

Is there a way to ensure that all flip flops default to 0 once I power the circuit on?

Please help me :)

Comment: Can you add any resistors and capacitors? If so connect some capacitor from the FF clear terminals to GND. Then put some resistor from the clear terminals to power source. To start try values of 10K ohm and 0.1uF. You should be able to tie all FF clear terminals to the same R & C.

Comment: I only have resistors so I'll try with those. You're saying that I should end up with something like this?

Power -> 10K Ohms -> Clear?

Comment: No. Power -> 10K Ohms -> Clear -> 0.1uF -> GND.

Comment: The capacitor is necessary to hold the clear pins low a short while as the power comes up. This allows the FF's to initialize to LOW on their Q pins.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is nothing in the specifications, nor in the internal schematics, that defines what the outputs of a JK flip-flop should be at power-on.  The only way of getting a known state is to use the `CLR` input of the chip, which resets the whole chip into a known state.

The normal way of doing this is to hold `CLR` low for a short period while the chip powers up, and only then release it to HIGH.  The simplest way to do this is with a capacitor and resistor on the pin.

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPzFW5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You will need to experiment to get the component values right for your situation.  The larger the values the slower the capacitor will charge, and the longer the delay before the CLR pin goes high.  R2 acts as a "bleed" resistor to remove the charge from the capacitor ready for the next power-on. It should be much higher than the charge resistor R1 as the two of them act like a voltage divider defining the maximum level of the capacitor's charge.  It may or may not be needed depending on the self-discharge of the capacitor and leakage current of the CLR pin when VCC is removed.

Comment: Is it necessary to use CLR, or would it also be sufficient to clock the chip when J is high and K is low or vice versa?  Alternatively, are any JK chips not designed so that regardless of their initial state, the probability that they won't be in a valid state after a few clock pulses will not approach zero?

Comment: Well, that works too, but using the CLR pin does not require adding any additional reset logic to the J/K inputs.